# Animation does not work on 2nd ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a main page and subpage which is displayed via ajax call.
When I click on the menu and load a subpage I have this animation inside which works well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".transactions").on("click", function (something) {
    something.preventDefault();
    $(".alltransactions").hide().show();
  });

  $(".alltransactions").on("click", function (something2) {
    something2.preventDefault();
    $(".alltransactions").hide();
  });
});
```

But when I go back to the main page and the load subpage via ajax again the above  animation does not work anymore. I have to refresh the whole page to get it working again. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can we have a demo ?

Comment: Its because you are doing this in `document.ready function`. Put the animations in a function and then call the function in `document.ready function` and as well as in `ajax success/complete` function.

Comment: Thanks.. It works now, but is there any other, maybe more elegant way than calling for the function in the success call?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont wish to wrap the click event inside a function means you can just trigger those two events just by calling this on your success function..

Jquery:

```
     $.ajax({
        url: '',
        data: ,
        success: function (response) {
           $(".transactions").click();
           $(".alltransactions").click();
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I would like to keep everything on subpage.php, so I don't need to call any functions on the main.php (where user really stays all the time, subpage is loaded via ajax only)..

Comment: I have just suggested you the other way to achieve that as you have asked in your comment..